# BroadcastReceiver live cycle with AlarmManager?

Tags: android

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver

    private Intent intentOnAlaramReceiver;
    private AlarmManager alarmManager;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
```

in docs said:

> A BroadcastReceiver object is only valid for the duration of the call
>   to onReceive(Context, Intent). Once your code returns from this
>   function, the system considers the object to be finished and no longer
>   active.

but I am using `AlarmManager`. If my class is destroyed after `onReceive` how can i then use

```
alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

What is best practice for this that receiver is not destroyed. App must be alive more then one day...

Comment: What do you mean? How long do you expect one alarm to last for? Also, if `alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);` is inside `onReceive()`, it's still technically inside this `onReceive()`'s execution time,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cancel an alarm manager you should simply pass in the same PendingInent - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#cancel%28android.app.PendingIntent%29

So, you can do it whenever you want to cancel the alarm manager (for instance, if by pressing the button - OnClickListener. Or in onReceive itself).